# Error in MIPS division with single precision floating point numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to implement division of two numbers in MIPS, and I'm supposed to do the following: `10.0/2.5`

The code I'm trying is below one

```
 .data 
    float1 : .float 2.5 # declaring the floating values
    float2 : .float 10.0 # declaring the floating values
.text 
 main :

 l.s $f2, float1 # loading the floating values to regester
 l.s $f3 , float2 # loading the floating values to regester

 li $v0,2
 div.s $f1 , $f3 , $f2
 syscall
```

Comment: You forgot to say what the error is. Note that [system call 2](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) does not expect its argument in `$f1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the floating point value into register $f12

```
.data 
    float1 : .float 2.5 # declaring the floating values
    float2 : .float 10.0 # declaring the floating values
.text 
     main :

         l.s $f2, float1 # loading the floating values to regester
         l.s $f3 , float2 # loading the floating values to regester

         li $v0,2
         div.s $f12 , $f3 , $f2
         syscall
```

Register $a0 is normally checked when outputting a value via syscall but with a floating point register $f12 is checked. You can either save the value there directly or use move to copy it over

```
.data 
    float1 : .float 2.5 # declaring the floating values
    float2 : .float 10.0 # declaring the floating values
.text 
     main :

         l.s $f2, float1 # loading the floating values to register
         l.s $f3 , float2 # loading the floating values to register

         li $v0,2
         div.s $f1 , $f3 , $f2
         mov.s $f12, $f1
         syscall
```